# UITextField Editing Did Begin called on view endEditing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertview

This all works in my version that's on app store. However if I revert my git to that, it no longer works. It might be since I updated Xcode (now 6.3) but not sure. The issue is:

I show a UIAlert when my UITextField 'Editing Did Begin' handler is called.
The Alert warns the user 'Are you sure you want to edit this ?"

If the user clicks 'Cancel' then I call

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Previously in my app this had the effect of leaving the UITextField and closing the dialog.

Now after the UIAlert is hidden, focus is given back to the UITextField causing the UIAlert to be created and displayed again.

Question is, how to remove focus from the UITextField ? And why did it used to work, but doesn't any more ?

Also tried [sender resignFirstResponder] but this doesn't do the trick either.

Bit more info in response to comment: Here's the 'Did End Editing' handler code

```
- (IBAction)textFieldReturned:(id)sender
{   
[sender resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Show more of the code where you call `endEditing:`. Are you using a `UIAlertView` or a `UIAlertController`?

Comment: Again where are you calling `endEditing:` from? In other words, which `UIAlertViewDelegate` method?

Comment: FYI - you can't resign a text field from the "did end editing" handler. The "did end editing" handler is called when the text field has already resigned.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that I call the [self.view endEditing:YES] code from the Alert View handler on condition "Cancel" is chosen. So it's actually called from there.

Comment: Which `UIAlertViewDelegate` method is it in?

Comment: - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to stem from trying to resign the text field from the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method. This is too soon.

I suggest you implement the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method instead. This way, the alert is already dismissed when you resign the text field.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    } else {
        // handle other buttons
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks rmaddy, looks like I was using the wrong UIAlertView API call. Which worked fine until I guess a change in the app code and/or iOS pushed it over the edge. Good catch.

Comment: What I think happens in new iOS versions is the alert detects what has the first responder at the time it is displayed. And it resets the first responder when it is dismissed. This is why your text field was getting put back as the first responder when using the earlier delegate method.